# why does not update jdbc statement execute in oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, parameters, nested

I want to execute below code in java (eclips)
however I get no error in ide, no update any rows in oracle

below code is update_method

```
public void setUpdate(String statement,String par1,String par2)throws Exception

{
  System.out.println("this is setUpdate method"+statement);
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","ALBALOO","myjava123");
  st =con.prepareStatement(statement);
  st.setString(1, par1);
  st.setString(2,par2);
  st.executeUpdate();
  // con.commit();
 }
```

and below one is for caller method

```
st="update newslables3 set nlable='1' where hhmm in (SELECT hhmm FROM newslables3 where hhmm not between '0830' and '1130') and yymmdd between ? and ? ";       
              db.setUpdate(st,priceSet[i][3],priceSet[i+1][3]);
```

my oracle version is 10g xe

Comment: Is this done within some transaction? Maybe it rolls back outside of this method call.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis since this is the whole code, then there is no transaction.

Comment: Silly question, did you trying running the update manually to see if it does what you expect?

Comment: Does the SQL statement updates the DB if run directly on the DB using some IDE ?

Comment: Have you verified if this SQL can be executed on your Oracle database and that actually updates the desired data with the parameters you sent? If so, then this code should work (assuming that the connection has AUTOCOMMIT property in `true`).